# How to click on outside of a div based on the value of inside value?

Tags: node.js, automation, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I want to click the class "include-icon" based on the user input. Check the below example:

```
<div class="item _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-80">
            <div class="content _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-80">
                  <inventory-item class="_ngcontent-EXCHANGE-48 _nghost-EXCHANGE-81">
                        <div class="itemName _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-81">Option 1
                        </div>
                  </inventory-item>
            </div>
            <div class="selections _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-80">
                  <material-button animated="true" class="include-icon _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-80 _nghost-EXCHANGE-2"
                        icon="" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false" elevation="4">
                  </material-button>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-80">
            <div class="content _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-80">
                  <inventory-item class="_ngcontent-EXCHANGE-48 _nghost-EXCHANGE-81">
                        <div class="itemName _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-81">Option 2
                        </div>
                  </inventory-item>
            </div>
            <div class="selections _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-80">
                  <material-button animated="true" class="include-icon _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-80 _nghost-EXCHANGE-2"
                        icon="" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false" elevation="4">
                  </material-button>
            </div>
      </div>

<div class="item _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-80">
            <div class="content _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-80">
                  <inventory-item class="_ngcontent-EXCHANGE-48 _nghost-EXCHANGE-81">
                        <div class="itemName _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-81">Option N
                        </div>
                  </inventory-item>
            </div>
            <div class="selections _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-80">
                  <material-button animated="true" class="include-icon _ngcontent-EXCHANGE-80 _nghost-EXCHANGE-2"
                        icon="" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false" elevation="4">
                  </material-button>
            </div>
      </div>
```

So in the above example, there are three options: Option 1, Option 2 and Option N. If a user inputs Option 2, I want the puppeteer to click include-icon just below it and same for others.

Right now I am able to get the input from user and store it in a variable but not able to click on that specific class "include-icon"

Comment: what do you mean by 'user inputs Option 2'?

Comment: it'll be taken as input using the terminal. It's a string

Comment: @domlas can u help?

Comment: Hi not sure if i am understanding properly. You want to click on element based on the text in it? If so i can provide simple snippet

Comment: suppose the script name is "script.js" so on terminal I write node script.js Option 1. Now I can get the input from the terminal using the args array. Now I want puppeteer to match which div has  Option 1 and click the include-icon class which is just outside of its div